# Mount Canon PowerShot SD780 in Mac OS Snow Leopard as drive to get card contents?

Tags: macos, usb, camera, sd-card, memory-card

Is there any way to browse the contents of an SD card inside my canon digital camera using my macbook pro?

I am trying to move the contents of the SD card to =a new SD card (with larger capacity).

I do not have a card reader, only the usb cable that comes with the camera.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hook up a digital camera to a Mac by default it will act just like as if you were using a card reader. (Assuming you haven't installed the manufacturer's software and they don't play around with it). It will appear as a second drive and more than likely Image Capture or iPhoto will open up on mounting. You can safely quit the application and drag the `DCIM` folder from the camera to your hard drive (if needing to swap cards) or direct to the newer SD card.

Comment: iPhoto does open up but i do not see a secondary drive on my desktop or anywhere for that matter.

Comment: Then that camera is probably not compatible with Apple's mass storage drivers. Card readers are like $15.